# Edit AngularJS pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I recently bought a [Template webpage](http://flat.ideanetwork.co) with AngularJS. But I can't edit any content of that

When I use "Inspect elements" in my browser, I can see all of tags such as "div", "table", "a" and etc., But in page source I just can see some tags like "script" and "link"

For example [THIS PAGE](http://flat.ideanetwork.co/angular/?layout=0#/app/dashboard) (Unfortunately this link has expired)

How can I edit pages content?

Comment: Markups are generated in runtime with Angular.You should learn Angular and make your desired changes in javascript code or if your changes are involving static html then you should change template files.

Comment: Need I edit generators? If yes, Where are them?

Comment: In which part you wanna make changes?

Comment: for example sidebar in [this page](http://flat.ideanetwork.co/angular/?layout=0#/app/dashboard) and in total I need to customize all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Script folder there is a file config.router.js , where you can find the list of the html page.

like this is your url : http://flat.ideanetwork.co/angular/?layout=0#/app/dashboard

you have to refer templateURl for the html page.

for that you have to check below code in config.router.js file

```
.state('app.dashboard', {
              url: '/dashboard',
              templateUrl: dashboard,
              data : { title: 'Dashboard' },
              controller: "ChartCtrl",
              resolve: load(['scripts/controllers/chart.js'])
            })
```

Similarly you can check for other pages.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically `Angular` uses logics from controllers to generate markup.If you wanna make changes in generated markups then you should make changes in `controllers` , `directives`, ...  else if you want to make some minor changes in static `HTMLs` merely then you most probability should make some changes in `template` files.At the end it totally depends on your template's code , and it requires we see the code inside template files.